# How to check Log4j in Magento installation?

Tags: magento2, security, elasticsearch, server-setup

I don't know if my Magento server is infected by [Log4j](https://www.cisa.gov/uscert/ncas/current-activity/2021/12/10/apache-releases-log4j-version-2150-address-critical-rce), how could I check it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have ElasticSearch installed, the chances are that you have a vulnerability in your server. You need to update your ElasticSearch to the version launched Dec 13, 2021.

Running this command below you can check the Log4j version installed, **the versions 2.0 to 2.14.1 are affected**.

```
dpkg -l|grep log4j;
```

You can find more details [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-avoid-log4j-your-magento-rafael-corr%C3%AAa-gomes).

Answer (score 1):

As i read on Elastic ([elastic.co](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/apache-log4j2-remote-code-execution-rce-vulnerability-cve-2021-44228-esa-2021-31/291476)) older Log4J versions could be also vulnerable too. This might be relevant for older Magento 2 installations with an older ElasticSearch setup or even for Magento 1 Shops that get patches from [MageOne](https://mage-one.com/de/patches-for-magento-1/) using ElasticSearch. If updating ElasticSearch is not an possible, setting the Dlog4j2 formatMsgNoLookups option to true should stop the lookup function and fix the gap.

> In versions 1.17.0-1.28.0, the issue can be mitigated manually by setting system property -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true.

On my setup I found the options file at */etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options*, added the option and restarted ElasticSearch afterwards.

To get fully sure that log4j on other setups with Magento is not installed i also checked for relevant .jar files.

```
find / -name '*.jar'
```

Sometimes the log4j jar can be packed into another jar as mentioned in that [post](https://u-labs.de/forum/security-177/schwere-luecke-in-log4j-cvss-10-10-zahlreiche-java-anwendungen-betroffen-u-a-apple-steam-twitter-amazon-mehr-cve-2021-44228-40662). So this simple find statement wouldn't find it. For that you can search for the class "JndiLookup" in packed jar files with

```
sudo find / -name *.jar -exec sh -c "if zipinfo {} | grep JndiLookup; then echo -e '{}\n'; fi" ;
```

See video on [u-labs.de](https://u-labs.de/forum/security-177/schwere-luecke-in-log4j-cvss-10-10-zahlreiche-java-anwendungen-betroffen-u-a-apple-steam-twitter-amazon-mehr-cve-2021-44228-40662)